# Select from two tables where date are similar but remove the time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get one table from two tables but I need the records to be synchronized by the same date without the time

```
select  *
from Transactions , SellerIPLogins
where Transactions.SellerId =SellerIPLogins.SellerId
  and Transactions.SellerId=3141 and Transactions.Payment>1
  and **Transactions.Date=SellerIPLogins.Date**
order by Transactions.Date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) method to convert datetime to date:

```
select  *
    from Transactions , SellerIPLogins
    where Transactions.SellerId =SellerIPLogins.SellerId
      and Transactions.SellerId=3141 and Transactions.Payment>1
      and Convert(date,Transactions.Date)=Convert(date,SellerIPLogins.Date)
    order by Transactions.Date desc
```

Comment: This is not a very good answer. Please post a description and not just code.

Comment: @JamieRees, Ok but in real time answering best approach is post a brief answer and then edit it in later time to have a complete answer.